# Change file format to upload document

Tags: node.js, multer

I am beginner and trying to learn on uploading file. I want to change code for image file mimetype to file like pdf, doc and pdf. But when I try to look for example for this filetype, I cannot find it. Usually it is for image type.

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg')
    cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
```

I know it is silly question but to change the mimetype to  format file  like pdf, doc, pptx. It is correct to do like this?

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'application/msword' || file.mimetype === 'application/pdf' || file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation')
    cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
```

I really appreciate if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Image types are just one class of MIME types, other MIME types like `application/msword` are also possible.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering.. If you dont mind, may I know if I  I do the code it correctly or do I missing something.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. But you should try it out and perhaps use a debugger to see what's exactly going on.